# Поиск по выпадающему меню

Tags: php, mysql

Есть выпадающие меню которое берет информацию из БД, подскажите как можно в нем реализовать поиск по колонке aboutStl?

```
 echo "<form method='post' action='stl.php'><select name='id'>";

 for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++)
                  {

                        $sql=mysql_query("select * from `figures` where `id`='".$i."' order by `aboutStl`");
                        while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                        {
                                echo "<option value='".$s['id']."'>".$s['aboutStl']."</option>";

                        }
                        $sec=$s['id'];
                        echo "<br>";

                  }

                  echo "</select>
                        <input type='submit' name='action' value='Выбрать'>

                        </form>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам просто нужно сделать поиск по значениям всех `<option>`, почему бы не воспользоваться каким нибудь плагином селектов? Например вот этим: https://github.com/HemantNegi/jquery.sumoselect.

Демо:http://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/sumoselect_demo.html

Так же, можно запилить JS, который будет искать по полям прямо в браузере. Например такой (писал на коленке, вроде работает :) ):

```js
var select = document.getElementById("filterableSelect");
var oldOptions = Array.apply(undefined, select.options); // копируем все OPTION. По ним будем искать

document.getElementById('selectFilter').onkeyup = function(e) {
  // спец. сочетания пропускаем
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) return;

  select.options.length = 0;
  var regexp = new RegExp(this.value, "ig");
  for (var i = 0; i < oldOptions.length; i++) {
    if (oldOptions[i].innerText.search(regexp) >= 0) {
      select.appendChild(oldOptions[i]);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="selectFilter" placeholder="Введи текст для поиска" />
<select name='id' id="filterableSelect">
  <option value="1">Текст 1</option>
  <option value="2">Текст 2</option>
  <option value="3">Я тоже текст</option>
  <option value="4">тут этого слова нет</option>
  <option value="5">и тут тоже нет</option>
  <option value="6">А тут текст снова есть</option>
</select>
```

**UPD**
Код для нескольких селектов и инпутов

```js
searchebleSelect("filterableSelect", "selectFilter");
searchebleSelect("filterableSelect2", "selectFilter2");


// функция создания поиска по селекту
function searchebleSelect(selectId, filterInputId) {
  if (window.oldSelectOptions === undefined) window.oldSelectOptions = [];

  // складываем текущие option селекта в глобальный массивы
  window.oldSelectOptions[selectId] = Array.apply(undefined, document.getElementById(selectId).options);
  var input = document.getElementById(filterInputId);
  // сохраняем в инпуте инфу о привязаном селекте
  input.dataset.searchSelectId = selectId;

  // отработка нажатия клавиши
  input.onkeyup = function(e) {
    // спец. сочетания пропускаем
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey) return;

    // Получаем список исходный option селекта
    var options = window.oldSelectOptions[this.dataset.searchSelectId];
    // Получаем селект, с которым будем работать
    var select = document.getElementById(this.dataset.searchSelectId);
    // Очищаем селект
    select.options.length = 0;
    var regexp = new RegExp(this.value, "ig");
    // Перебираем все option
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      // Если есть совпадение текста
      if (options[i].innerText.search(regexp) >= 0) {
        // Добавляем option в селект
        select.appendChild(options[i]);
      }
    }
  };

}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
Select #1
</h1>
  <input type="text" id="selectFilter" placeholder="Введи текст для поиска" />
  <select name='id' id="filterableSelect" multiple size="10">
    <option value="1">Текст 1</option>
    <option value="2">Текст 2</option>
    <option value="3">Я тоеж текст</option>
    <option value="4">тут этого слова нет</option>
    <option value="5">и тут тоже нет</option>
    <option value="6">А тут текст снова есть</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>
Select #2
</h1>
  <input type="text" id="selectFilter2" placeholder="Введи текст для поиска" />
  <select name='id' id="filterableSelect2" multiple size="10">
    <option value="1">Другой - Текст 1</option>
    <option value="2">Другой - Текст 2</option>
    <option value="3">Другой - Я тоеж текст</option>
    <option value="4">Другой - тут этого слова нет</option>
    <option value="5">Другой - и тут тоже нет</option>
    <option value="6">Другой - А тут текст снова есть</option>
  </select>

</div>
```

Comment: у меня получается только к 1 из 2 применить https://jsfiddle.net/srh24hz6/
Я пытался на 2 файла разбить и свести в 1 место все равно не получается,пытался поменять значение id, все равно ищет только по 1,как можно сделать чтобы сразу в 2 местах искал

Comment: Все верно. Вопрос был только про один селект. Чтобы сделать для двух, нужно менять код, например, так: https://jsfiddle.net/rame0/jh6g4srx/. Сделал функцию для создания поиска по селекту(ам)

Comment: спасибо !все получилось)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов. Если быстродействие не критично, можно использовать LIKE:

```
select * from `figures` where `aboutStl` like '%$searchstring%'
```

`%` заменяет любое количество символов. Поэтому подобрать строку, начинающуюся на поисковую фразу можно поставив `%` только в конце:

```
select * from `figures` where `aboutStl` like '$searchstring%'
```

Подробнее читайте тут: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html

Еще вариант использовать полнотекстовый поиск. Его разумно использовать для поиска по нескольким полям, или если поисковая строка содержит несколько слов, или если требуется найти неточные совпадения. Но для этого нужно сначала создать индекс FullText для поиска по нему. Подробнее читайте тут: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать jQuery библиотеку [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)